# Windows Phone how to detect scroll position of a browser control

Tags: c#, javascript, scroll, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am developing a browser app for Windows Phone 8. I want to detect the scroll position, so that I can show the address bar only when user is at top of the page. I also want to restore the current scroll position after a page refresh.

I cannot inject javascript into the page because obviously the content is from all over the web.

So far I am able to determine if user is scrolling up or down based on [this idea](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/).

If I can inject javascript, I probably could use `InvokeScript` and detect if page scroll is at the very top

```
window.onscroll = function(ev)
{
    var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
    var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
    D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;

if (D.scrollTop == 0)
    {
        alert("top");
    }        
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L38a9/1/)

So I wonder if anyone has any suggestion to achieve this. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Is it possible to use `IFRAME` and place my javascript there while the external websites are loaded inside the `IFRAME`?